# luabind and dynamic properties

Tags: c++, lua, luabind

I want create a class with dynamic properties. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int GetValue(string str)
    {
        return smap[str];
    }
    void SetValue(string str, int i)
    {
        smap[str] = i;
    }

private:

    std::map<string, int> smap;
};
```

how can I bind this class to lua with luabind or mluabind to use in lua like this:

```
local myclass a;
a.var1 = 5;
a.var2 = 10;
print(a.var1, a.var2);
```

not like this:

```
local myclass a;
a.SetValue("var1", 5);
a.SetValue("var2", 10);
print(a.GetValue("var1"), a.GetValue("var2"));
```

var1, var2 - variable names which I know only in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Lua metatables.

For each table in Lua, you can provide a metatable, which is a table that can be used to overload the table's operators and also how does it access its members. In other words, it can be used to provide a method that describes what should happen whenever someone attempts to access a member inside the table. See the [Metatables chapter in PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.html), and its 'Table-Access Metamethods' section in particular.

In your case, you can create two C++ functions that will provide a read and a write access to your C++ class. You can then bind them into Lua, and overload your Lua table so that it calls these functions whenever you try to either read a value that's in the table or write a value into it.